# CORS error after the second time I send the same get request

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch

This is the line of code that gives me the error:

```
let obj = await (await fetch(url)).json();
```

The first time I call the function that runs the code above, everything goes smoothly, I get the JSON response I'm looking for.

The second time I call it in the same browser session however I get:

Access to fetch at **** from origin **** has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I can't work out why. If I refresh the page and try again it works, but if I try once more without refreshing then it fails.

UPDATE:
I solved it. the status code for the error I get is 429, which is the Too Many Requests response status code, I have to wait some 20 seconds between a request and another, which is a pain but oh well.

Comment: Why await twice? Please post a [mcve]

Comment: @mplungjan `fetch` returns a promise and `.json` returns a promise. How would you call it?

Comment: I’d proces the data in the then instead

Comment: @mplungjan That's also my preferred approach, but many people consider mixing `await` and `.then` bad practice. I prefer `await fetch(url).then(res => res.json())`, but not all teams allow it.

Comment: So don't use await. there is no need I see. `fetch(url).then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => process(data);`

Comment: @mplungjan I guess `let obj = await (await fetch(url)).json();` is simpler for beginners. TBH I don't see the problem with two `await`. The code is shorter and clearer.

Comment: Seems it gives issues. So why not use the default MDN suggestion?

Comment: @mplungjan The `fetch` produces a CORS error. I bet, it has nothing to do with two `await`. But it's worth a try.

Comment: I think it is an X/Y problem. Why would it work the first time and not the second time? Sounds like the origin changed between the calls

Comment: @mplungjan the first await is for the promise returned by the fetch, the second is because .json() also returns a promise. I have to use them both. I'm not sure what you mean with x/y problem. i do not change any headers or code between the two requests. simply if the user clicks a button the same function is run again with the same exact parameters (which in this case are none)

Answer (score -1):

I solved this issue with this chrome extension

[link here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf)

> in case upper link does not work then use this link below
> [link 2](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Also it seems you have an X/Y problem and you solved it with a sledgehammer

Comment: I solved it. it wasn't that, i simply wasn't waiting enough time between requests